# How can I move multiple files to a directory while changing their names and extensions using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

There are multiple files in `/opt/dir/ABC/` named `allfile_123-abc allfile_123-def allfile_123-ghi allfile_123-xxx`.

I need the files to be named `new_name-abc.pgp new_name-def.pgp new_name-ghi.pgp new_name-xxx.pgp` and then moved to `/usr/tst/output`

```
for file in /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123* ; 
do mv $file /usr/tst/output/"$file.pgp"; 
rename allfile_123 new_name /usr/tst/output/*.pgp ; done
```

I know the above doesn't work because `$file = /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*`.  Is it possible to make this work, or is it a different command instead of 'for loop'?

This is for the Autosys application in which the jil contains a command to pass to the command line of a linux server running bash.

I could only find versions of each part of my question but not altogether and I was hoping to keep it on the command line of this jil.  Unless a script is absolutely necessary.

Comment: You say `/opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*` doesn't work?  It will work if the glob pattern is accurate.  You should use double quotes around the `"$file"` when you reference it (e.g. in `mv "$file" "/usr/tst/output/$file.pgp"`), but that's not your immediate problem.  What are you passing to the script?

Comment: I'm not passing anything to a script, this is all on the command line.  The error I'm receiving is `mv: cannot move `/opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123-abc' to `/usr/tst/output//opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123-abc.pgp': No such file or directory.`

Comment: `mv "$file" /usr/tst/output/new_name"${file#allfile_123}".pgp` ought to work

Comment: You just need to do `file=$(basename "$file")` or use `${file##*/}` to remove the leading components of the path.

Comment: The application passing the command to the command line isn't running it from the starting directory.  I have to write it directory specific so the command can be run from any directory.  I hope I'm explaining that right.

Comment: Use double or triple backquotes around a command string that contains embedded backquotes.  For example, ```mv: cannot move `/opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123-abc' to `/usr/tst/output//opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123-abc.pgp': …``` — I used triple backquotes around the verbiage.

Comment: You might need to use `shopt -s nullglob` so that if the glob pattern doesn't match, you end up with nothing, not a copy of the glob string.

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm way out of my element now... I don't know what glob is and I'm not sure what basename is or how to use it properly either.  Especially within the context of my current cmd... I'll try to look into this today... thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the loop, you can do this with just `rename` and `mv`:

```
rename -v 's/$/.pgp/' /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*
rename -v s/allfile_123/new_name/ /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*
mv /opt/dir/ABC/new_name* /usr/tst/output/
```

But I'm not sure the `rename` you are using is the same as mine.
However,
since the replacement you want to perform is fairly simple,
it's easy to do in pure Bash:

```
for file in /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*; do
    newname=new_name${file##*allfile_123}.gpg
    mv "$file" /usr/tst/output/"$newname"
done
```

If you want to write it on a single line:

```
for file in /opt/dir/ABC/allfile_123*; do newname=new_name${file##*allfile_123}.gpg; mv "$file" /usr/tst/output/"$newname"; done
```

Comment: This looks like the Perl-based `rename` (sometimes called `prename`); the code in the question looks like it is using the other version — I'm not sure exactly where it's from (maybe GNU fileutils).  I dislike the insipid functionality of the alternative — basically, I only use the Perl version.

Comment: I used semicolon to seperate each line on the same line and received the following error "mv cannot stat /opt/dir/ABC/new_name*': No such file or directory.

Comment: @Emile The error message tells you that there are no files with that prefix. Either the renaming didn't work or there was nothing to rename. Run the commands step by step, and verify each step works as expected. Once you have a working solution, use `&&` instead of `;` to chain the commands together. That way the chain of commands will stop when a command fails, without executing the rest.

Comment: @Emile I added a pure Bash implementation in my answer, that might work better for your case.

Comment: @janos Thanks!  The for loop worked for what I was trying to achieve, and I was able to use it from one command line input instead of a script as well.  Thanks again!